# Magento 2 Container renders outside of parent container

Tags: magento2, template

I have the container page-wrapper, and inside is footer-container.  When I check the rendered HTML, the footer container is actually outside the page-wrapper div.  How do I keep it inside of the parent div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have an error in your layout files. Make sure that the block that contains the footer container is a child of the `page-wrapper` element's block, and is rendered inside it as well.